# Where to find quality beginner sheet music for guitar?

Tags: guitar, beginner, sight-reading

I am trying to improve my sight reading skills on guitar. Any recommendations of books or websites is appreciated. 
(I would prefer the sheet music to be without tabs beneath it if that's possible)

Comment: If you find it then tell me, I gave up learning to read sheet music for guitar and started on piano because there aren't many resources for this. I just googled this and this seems to be credible though I haven't really checked it out http://www.mojouniverse.com/site_reading.html

Comment: We need to know whether it's classical, acoustic, electric, dots/chords, jazz, etc. They're all going to be rather different in their approaches.

Comment: Not classical guitar I use a pick/fingerstyle on my acoustic. Any genre would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've purchased sheet music from this site before with good results:

https://www.sheetmusicdirect.us

Lots of songs avaialable on there in a variety of formats with and without tab.

If that doesn't work, googling "guitar sheet music" provides a lot of results.

Answer (score -2):

I recomend a book of Tarrega's works. Lagrima is a great place to start.